# Compilation issue when passing a string variable to a function instead of a fixed character array

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm using the initializer list method for my class constructor. I initialize my variables by calling a getData member function of the dataRegistry Class which provides the data to load into my class' variables.  The getData method is normally called by passing a character array which contains the name of the data to be loaded.

For e.g. an initializer list looks like the following:

```
    dataItem1(dr.getData("Pop.Stats1")),
    dataItem2(dr.getData("Pop.Stats2"))
```

However, due to the way the names of provided, I need to pull the name of the dataset from a user class and then append the variable name to pass to the getData method. Something like this:

```
    datasetName(user.getAttributeString("DataSetName")),
    dataItem1(dr.getData(datasetName + ".Stats1")),
    dataItem2(dr.getData(datasetName + ".Stats2"))
```

where datasetName is defined as a std::string variable.

However, this throws the following error:

```
     no matching function for call to 'DataRegistry::GetData(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

Since the implementation of the getData method is not provided to me and I know that it works when I just pass a char array (e.g."Pop.Stat1") to the function, I suspected this was because the function accepted character arrays only. So, I tried:

```
    datasetName(user.getAttributeString("DataSetName")),
    dataItem1(dr.getData(strcat(datasetName.c_str() , ".Stats1"))),
    dataItem2(dr.getData(strcat(datasetName.c_str() , ".Stats2"))),
```

but this throws the error:

```
    error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
    initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcat(char*, const char*)'
```

I'm clueless as to what's going wrong? Please advise!

Comment: What is the declaration of GetData()?

Comment: You can't just append something to `std::string::c_str()` with strcat.

Comment: In the error message it clearly states "`GetData(...`" but in your code you use `getData()`... That may be a problem.

Comment: It could be that getData() returns a char* ...

Comment: The issue was not with the GetData method name but with the way I was using strcat, rightfully pointed out by Brian.

Using `(datasetName+".Stats1").c_str()` on the whole things sorted out the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost, though using `strcat` on the return value of `c_str()` causes undefined behaviour. Just do:

```
(datasetName + ".Stats1").c_str()
```

so the whole line looks like

```
dataItem1(dr.getData((datasetName + ".Stats1").c_str())),
```

Because you're concatenating `".Stats1"` onto `datasetName` via `string::operator+`, then you want to get the `const char*` to that string, so you use `c_str()` on the return value of `operator+`.

You need the parentheses around it because `.` has higher precedence than `+`, so if the parens weren't there, you'd be calling `c_str()` on ".Stats1" (instead of the return value of `+`) which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

`datasetName.c_str()` returns a `const char *` - as in, you can't modify it - it's a pointer to the internal data of the `std::string`

Furthermore ... even if it were just a `char *` you can't just append data onto the end of it and call it good - you don't have the memory allocated for that.

Append to the `std::string` and *then* call `c_str()`

Answer (score 1):

If datasetName is an `std::string` then the type of `datasetName + "str"` is also `std::string`, so you need c_str() to get `const char*`.

```
dataItem1(dr.getData( (datasetName + ".Stats1").c_str() )),
dataItem2(dr.getData( (datasetName + ".Stats2").c_str() )
```

However, right after `getData` returns, value of `(datasetName + ".Stats1").c_str()` is freed up, so be sure that `getData` copies the content of the char array.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. The method c_str returns a const char*, but the first parameter of strcat is char*.